# Tightening a quick release wheel and having one spring

Tags: quick-release

I’m fairly new to mountain biking and I’ve recently removed a quick release wheel and I’m trying to reattach it. However if I tighten it too much it makes a squeak noise around the axle. Also I’ve noticed that I only have one spring and I’m sure I’ve bought it from the shop like that.

Anyway my question is should the quick release nut be tighten as much as physically possible? And also is it safe & normal for a bike to have only one spring (on the quick release)?

Comment: Does the squeaky noise come from the axle or from the brakes? Is it unusually hard to rotate the wheel?

Comment: Normally there should be two springs, though the springs aren't all that important.  They really just serve to "center" the skewer while installing/removing the wheel.  But the QR should be quite tight -- it should require a bit of effort to close the lever.

Comment: Along with what @danial stated - squeaks are typcvially cause when when things are loose, not tight. Without tools, it is very unlikely you have the ability to overtightened the QR, (unless you are a gorrila). The rule of thumb is the QR should leave a dent in your palm when you tighten it.

Answer (score 5):

The springs simply keep the quick release (QR) skewer centered in the wheel hub, making it easier to insert the hub (and wheel) into the frame dropouts.  It has no safety function other than to facilitate seating the wheel correctly.  If the wheel is not seated correctly in the drops when you tighten the QR then you run the risk of the wheel coming out during a ride. That said, this is true whether or not you still have the QR springs.

When tightening the QR, it should be tight enough that the QR lever leaves a mark in the palm of your hand.

Finally, if you are getting a squeaky metal noise your single QR spring may be on backwards, or as pointed out by Daniel R Hicks' comment, the two springs could have gotten combined together. First check to see that you only indeed only have one spring and that two springs haven't gotten entangled.  When placing the springs back on the QR, the narrow end should point toward the hub, the wide end toward the end of the QR skewer. If the spring was installed backwards the wide end of the spring can get jammed into the frame and hub axle, potentially making a squeaking noise when tightening the QR.

Comment: Or the two springs may have gotten pressed together.

Comment: @DanielRHicks - yes, another solid possibility - I have added it to the text.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a more objective rule of thumb regarding skewer tightness it that you should begin to feel resistance when the skewer handle is halfway closed, which is when it's sticking straight out (in-line/parallel with the hub).  My experience has been if it begins to tighten before half-way, it won't close without leaving more than an impression in my palm. And if too loose, the pressure to complete the closure just doesn't "ramp-up" the last several millimeters, so open it back up and give it another half turn and see then.

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

If you're missing a spring from your QR Skewer, you'll be fine. I only have one spring at the moment also and haven't had any issues.

As for tightening the nut before locking the QR down, it should be tight, but not too tight so that you don't bend the QR lever. You shouldn't have to break a sweat to close the lever.

Comment: "break a sweat" is a very subjective measure of force.  It should be tight enough that the QR lever just makes a mark in the palm of your hand.

Comment: @Rider_X That's also pretty subjective.